# Connect a node to another node to be created in the future

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing a parser for a text file of nodes and connections with Python.
For example, the text file looks like this:

```
a
b
   b <-> a   # exists a connection between a/b
c
d
   d <-> e   # PROBLEM! this node connect to another node not yet being created
e
```

This is what am I trying to do with parsing.py

```
#blah blah    
for line in raw:
    if is_node(line):
        add_node(NodeBuilder(line))
    elif is_connection(line):
        nameEndA, nameEndB = parse_connection(line)
        endA = nodeDict[nameEndA]
        # this line will receive KeyError because sometimes \
        # the connection specifier is written before definition of the node
        endB = nodeDict[nameEndB]    

        endA.connect(endB)

#definition of NodeBuilder and other functions
```

An intuitive way to fix this is delaying the connection phase, but this indicates parsing have to split into 2 parts, where Node object has to deal with the raw text.

```
#blah blah    
for line in raw:
    if is_node(line):
        add_node(NodeBuilder(line))
    elif is_connection(line):
        nameEndA, nameEndB = parse_connection(line)
        endA = nodeDict[nameEndA]
        try:
            endB = nodeDict[nameEndB]
            endA.connect(endB)
        except KeyError:
            endA.txt2Parse(line)

for node in nodes:
    if node.txt2Parse:
        node.parse_and_connect()     # has to parse raw data in Node object!!!
```

Is there a better way to design this without the bad encapsulation?

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, give a [mcve] clearly demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `parse_connection(line)` returns the string names of the nodes,
you could use

```
    for name in (nameEndA, nameEndB):
        if not name in nodeDict:
            add_node(NodeBuilder(name))
```

to add the node(s) before making a connection.

---

Add the check before accessing the node names from `nodeDict`:

```
for line in raw:
    if is_node(line):
        add_node(NodeBuilder(line))
    elif is_connection(line):
        nameEndA, nameEndB = parse_connection(line)
        for name in (nameEndA, nameEndB):
            if not name in nodeDict:
                add_node(NodeBuilder(name))
        endA = nodeDict[nameEndA]
        endB = nodeDict[nameEndB]    
        endA.connect(endB)
```